# How do I deduplicate words in a character variable?

Tags: sas

I have a variable that contains a list of words that I'm going to use for a process, and need to keep in one variable (at least, by the end of this question/answer it needs to be back in one variable).  I need that list of words to be deduplicated.

What is the most efficient way to deduplicate the variable?  Can I do it without splitting the variable into multiple variables?

For example, I have this dataset:

```
data have;
  x = "A B C D E F E G H B I A B D J K";
run;
```

and I'd like to return this dataset.

```
data want;
  x = "A B C D E F G H I J K";
run;
```

If I had multiple variables, I could do soething like

```
data want;
  set have;
  array myvar /* the variables I do not have*/ ;
  call sortc(of myvar[*]);
run;
```

But that won't work with just one variable, sorting the words inside that variable.

The actual strings may be more than one character long, if that's relevant (so please don't give a solution that *only* works for one character).  Words do not need to be sorted in any particular order, and which duplicate you remove is immaterial - "C F E G H I A B D J K" is just as valid as "A B C D E F G H I J K" or any other combination.

Comment: Joe. I hope NORC pays well. You know this stuff inside and out. 

If it doesn't you should definitely look into the financial services sector. I know one in Chicago that would pick you up in a heart-beat.

Answer (score 3):

Just build up a new list by adding each word that is not already in the new list.  If you want you can specify the delimiter list to use in the function calls.

```
data have;
  old = 'A B C D E F E G H B I A B D J K';
run;

data want ;
  set have;
  length word new $200 ;
  do i=1 to countw(old);
    word=scan(old,i);
    if indexw(new,word) then continue;
    new=catx(' ',new,word);
  end;
  put (old new) (=/);
run;

old=A B C D E F E G H B I A B D J K
new=A B C D E F G H I J K
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this problem consists of using `call scan` to iterate through the words, and using `findw` to compare this to the substring that is remaining, to remove duplicates.

```
data have;
  x = "A B C D E F E G H B I A B D J K";             *initialize dataset;
  do count = countw(x) to 2 by -1;                   *iterate over words (right to left here);
    call scan(x,count,position,length);              *look for the first word;
    _curword = substr(x,position,length);            *for simplicity, I make a temporary variable with the current word and the current rest of string.  This could be done without these two variables just including them in the `findw` itself.;
    _restofstring = substr(x,1,position-1);          *The remaining (to the left) portion of the string that could have duplicates;
    put "|"_curword "|"_restofstring "|";
    put position= length=;
    if findw(_restofstring,trim(_curword)) then do;  *If a duplicate is found;
      put "Deleting" _curword=;                      *delete it below;
      x = substr(x,1,position-1) || substr(x,position+length+1);
    end;
  end;
  put x=;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could output each word to a separate record, sort it & remove duplicates, then flatten back down to a single record.

```
data have ;
  x = "A B C D E F E G H B I A B D J K" ;
  id = _n_ ;
  do i = 1 to countw(x) ;
    word = scan(x,i,' ') ;
    output ;
  end ;
run ;

proc sort data=have nodupkey ;
  by id word ;
run ;

data want ;
  set have ;
  by id ;
  length x $200. ; /* same length as 'x' in have dataset */
  retain x '' ;
  if first.id then call missing(x) ;
  x = catx(' ',x,word) ;
  if last.id then output ;
run ;
```

You can take this a stage further by creating a Macro-Function-Sandwich, utilising the power of `proc fcmp` and macros :

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.utility ;
  function dedupe(string $) $ ;
    length string $200 ;
    rc = run_macro('DEDUPE',string) ; /* call dedupe macro */
    if rc = 0 then return(strip(string)) ;
    else return('') ;
  endsub ;
quit ;
options cmplib=work.funcs ;

%MACRO DEDUPE ;
  data __dedupe ; 
    x = &STRING ; /* passed from proc fcmp with quotes */
    do i = 1 to countw(x) ;
      word = scan(x,i,' ') ;
      output ;
    end ;
  run ;
  proc sort data=__dedupe nodupkey ;
    by word ;
  run ;
  data _null_ ;
    set __dedupe end=eof ;
    length x $200 ;
    retain x '' ;
    x = catx(' ',x,word) ;
    if eof then call symput('STRING',strip(x)) ; /* return &STRING to proc fcmp */
  run ;
  /* cleanup */
  proc sql noprint ;
    drop table __dedupe ;
  quit ;
%MEND ;
```

Once defined, you can then use it like any other datastep function. The beauty of macros called within PROC FCMP is that they run independently 'on-the-side', away from the datastep in which the function is called.

```
data want ;
  x = "A B C D E F E G H B I A B D J K" ;
  x2 = dedupe(x) ;
run ;
```

You can then wrap the FCMP function in another macro, and call the function within a `%SYSFUNC`, so you can perform the same processing on macro variables :

```
%MACRO STRDEDUPE(STR) ;
  %SYSFUNC(dedupe(&STR))
%MEND ;

%LET X = A B C D E F E G H B I A B D J K ;
%PUT %STRDEDUPE(&X) ;
```

PROC FCMP Procedure > https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002890483.htm

Use the Full Power of SAS® in Your Function-Style Macros (SUGI Paper, 2012) > 
https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/004-2012.pdf

[Untested code, let me know if there's any errors]

Comment: I will have to try this tomorrow. My inclination is that this will be very slow, as fcmp tends to be in things like this, but it's definitely an interesting approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
  x = "A B C D E F E G H B I A B D J K";
  do i=1 to countw(x); 
  _x=prxchange('s/(\b\w+?\b)(.*?)(?=\1{1,})(.?)/$2 $3/i',-1,x);
  x=_x;
  end;
 drop i;
run;
proc print;
run;
```

Comment: Interesting. Some explanation would be helpful to make this a good answer.